# Is "Identity not verified" a problem? If so, how to solve it?

Tags: seo, googlebot, bing

When I select the context menu item "View Page Info" on my site (using Chrome), I see "Identity not verified"

Should I be:

(a) concerned
(b) angry
(c) nonchalant

?

If one of the first two, what can I do to "verify my identity"?

I have submitted my site to Google and Bing, it is hosted with Discount ASP.NET, and I have tweaked the SEO as much as practical.

Comment: It isn't "your" identity that needs to be verified.  Rather, it is the identity of your "site".

Comment: Right, I realize that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with SEO, Google, Bing, or any other website. You need to get an SSL certificate that verifies your identity for this to say your identity is verified.

Comment: Okay, how I get an SSL certificate, or first: what are the benefits of getting an SSL certificate?

Comment: [Why get an SSL certificate?](http://www.sslshopper.com/why-ssl-the-purpose-of-using-ssl-certificates.html). You can get one from a variety of places. I recommend checking out a few of them as prices can vary tremendously.

Comment: Based on what I read here: http://ezinearticles.com/?What-Are-The-Benefits-Of-An-SSL-Certificate?&id=7196300 and here: http://www.sslshopper.com/why-ssl-the-purpose-of-using-ssl-certificates.html, I probably don't need it for my site, as I don't sell anything directly from there. It would seem to be of primary advantage to give users a "good feeling" about the site; ISTM my web hosting company should be the one that takes care of this, so that all of their sites are "identified"

Comment: Yeah. The whole identity thing only comes if you have a trust relationship with your users. If you're not selling anything or requiring sensitive data you won't need to worry about this.